# JQuery is only working at a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm making a Search Bar overlay, got it completed and it supposed to work like the [Example](https://codepen.io/RTarson/pen/dMZMRx) I provided. But the JS only works fine either if I'm logged into WordPress or if my Window with is `>588px` then it works fine.

The website is [Tarson Pools](http://tarsonpools.com) click the Search Icon.

Below is my JQuery code (which works fine):

```
//Created by Ryan Tarson, Please do not copy be original
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
  console.log(wHeight);
  //search bar middle alignment
  $('#mk-fullscreen-searchform').css('top', wHeight / 2);
  //reform search bar
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    wHeight = window.innerHeight;
    $('#mk-fullscreen-searchform').css('top', wHeight / 2);
  });
  // Search
  $('#search-button').click(function() {
    console.log("Open Search, Search Centered");
    $("div.mk-fullscreen-search-overlay").addClass("mk-fullscreen-search-overlay-show");
  });
  $("a.mk-fullscreen-close").click(function() {
    console.log("Closed Search");
    $("div.mk-fullscreen-search-overlay").removeClass("mk-fullscreen-search-overlay-show");
  });
});
```

Comment: Define 'only works fine', what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @rsn Meaning works as intended.

Comment: What a mammoth of a source.. Could you post the css for the classes and IDs used above? Have you tried isolating the function, i.e., creating a blank .html and only using the essentials for this code to work?

Comment: Yes its up above click on `example`. From reviewing the only thing thats not working is the `onClick` method. It is moving the search bar to center in background. But the `onClick` Method doesnt work until Resolution/innerWindow is >855px

Comment: I'm at a loss why it wouldn't be working, the code is not super elegant but it should be working, I'm sorry I can't be more of a help.

On another note, I added a `z-index:2;` to your `.mk-fullscreen-close`, since that bothered me to no end. Also, to `#mk-fullscreen-search-input` I added a `max-width:800px` and a `width:80%` to help with the responsiveness. Aside from this, I have nothing, good luck!

Comment: @rsn It was the class that was with it. I have a YT banner that depends on a custom JQuery so it must now be outdated. or something cause my demo works fine with the `class` object with the icon

Comment: @rsn thank for your help. I walked away sat down for minute came back tried what I was thinking and it worked! So happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the Class assignment that was with the Search Icon.
After removing the line `class: col-mw-3` it ran fine, and in all of the browsers.
Also make sure nothing is covering the `<a>` Tag as well!